# How do I set and unset an observer in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, observers

I'm trying to understand the right way to go about setting and unsetting an observer within a Polymer component within `attached()` and `detached()` events, so it only starts watching after the element is attached. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no public API to imperatively add observers (but a private one exists), and no API at all to remove them.

The private function, `_addComplexObserverEffect(...)`, creates an observer on one or more properties. It's this function that processes each observer expression in the Polymer object's `observers` array. Note the caveat of using a private function is it could be unusable in the next release.

You could use it like this:

```
Polymer({
  ...,

  properties: {
    foo: String
  },

  attached: function() {
    this._addComplexObserverEffect('_fooChanged(foo)');
  },

  _fooChanged: function(foo) { ... }
});
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QGdGZG?editors=1011)

Comment: Are there any plans to be able to do this in the future? A public set and unset method?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a private method and its just a matter of timing and not a need to have *n dynamic observers*, just set a prop once the element has attached, add that prop to the observer and only execute when attached.

```
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-el',
    properties: {
      bar: String,
      attached: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      }
    },
    observers: [
      '_barChagned(bar, attached)'
    ],
    _barChagned: function(bar, att) {
      if(!att) return;
        // Do your stuff
    },
    attached: function() {
      this.set('attached', true);
    }
  });
```